# Searching in input gives incorrect date in material date picker need to convert it into UTC

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am extending MomentDateAdapter for my requirement. When i am selecting a date from the calendar i am getting the correct output but when i manually type something in the input field i get wrong output.

For the selected date i am using `_moment.utc({ year, month, date }).locale(navigator.language);` to convert the selected value to UTC format but i am not sure on how to do the same when user searches in the input field.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-date-adapter-overriding-h6zeds?file=app%2Fcustom-date-adapter.tsSteps).

to reproduce:

1. Try to select a value from calendar and see the console (notice the date is converted to UTC)
2. Now try to add a date manually by typing in and see the console (date is not converted to UTC).

Comment: have raised an issue on git as well: -https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adapt your `parse` method call of `moment` to:

```
return moment.utc(value, parseFormat, this.locale, true);
```

to get utc Date from your input.

Here is your adapted [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moment-date-adapter-overriding-owck49?file=app%2Fcustom-date-adapter.ts).

The methods `format` and `createDate` are called if you set your date via picker, the `parse` method is called if you set it via input.

Comment: in the same stackblitz url i shared i incorporated your changes but now i am facing another issue. when there is a time zone difference and i assign a date by default to the datepicker eg 06/03/2020. It shows the correct date in the input but when i open the calendar i see 06/04/2020 selected in the calendar. When i select something in calendar it works fine, this issue only occurs in case of a default value. if you could help me with this it would be awesome :)